# POST data using POSTMAN

Tags: c#, xml

so I've been having trouble using the POST method with C# and POSTMAN.
The GET works pretty fine but I'm getting an error on the POST method.
Here's my code:

```
public SaveProfileResponseDTO SaveProfileQuery(SaveProfileRequestDTO objProfileRequest)
    {
       SaveProfileResponseDTO objSaveProfileResponse;
       try
       {
           XElement xElement = XElement.Load(Path);

           XElement Student = (from u in xElement.Elements("Student")
                       where (string)u.Attribute("id") == objProfileRequest.StudentID.ToString()
                       select (u)).FirstOrDefault();

           Student.Element("Name").Value = objProfileRequest.Name;
           Student.Element("Gender").Value = objProfileRequest.Gender;

           xElement.Save(Path);

           objSaveProfileResponse = new SaveProfileResponseDTO()
           {
               Status = new ResponseCode()
               {
                   Code = StatusCodes.Success,
                   Message = StatusMessages.Success
               }
           };
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           objSaveProfileResponse = new SaveProfileResponseDTO()
           {
               Status = new ResponseCode()
               {
                   Code = StatusCodes.Error,
                   Message = StatusMessages.Error
               }
           };
       }
       return objSaveProfileResponse;
    }
```

This is my Controller:

```
       [Route("Profile")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Profile(SaveProfileRequestModel objSaveProfileRequestModel)
    {
        StudentManager = new StudentManager();
        SaveProfileRequestDTO objSaveProfileRequestDTO = new SaveProfileRequestDTO()
        {
            Gender = objSaveProfileRequestModel.Gender,
            Name = objSaveProfileRequestModel.Name,
            StudentID = objSaveProfileRequestModel.StudentID
        };
        SaveProfileResponseDTO objSavePofileResponse = StudentManager.SaveProfile(objSaveProfileRequestDTO);
        SaveProfileResponseModel objSaveProfileResponseModel = new SaveProfileResponseModel()
        {
            Status = objSavePofileResponse.Status
        };
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, objSavePofileResponse);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
I can also provide the GET method code if you want.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the error? Post that too.

Comment: Your explanation isn't very clear -  I assume that code is part of an MVC ASP.NET application, hence you're trying to expose an API called 'SaveProfileQuery'?  How are you posting to it, and what exact error are you getting? And what is the value of 'Path'?

Comment: One thing - your API will definitely fail if there is no student in the XML file with the matching id. You need code to create the new XElement in that case.

Comment: I'm getting server error, as if there's a problem reaching the file. But the thing is my GET method works perfectly with the same path value.

Comment: @DylanNicholson The POST method is intended to add a value to the XML file, so even if the ID doesn't exist in the database, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: But you have no code there that adds any elements to the XML file. I don't know how GET would be working properly either, unless you're very careful passing the `SaveProfileRequestDTO` parameter in the query string (possible but messy).  And you still haven't told us what the actual error is, or what exception is getting thrown in your code at what line. You have tried it with the debugger attached I assume?

Comment: @DylanNicholson I've added my Controller code, so you can have a better view on my code.
As I mentioned before, the GET method works fine, and I can provide the code if you want to see it.
On Postman, I'm not getting a result, I'm getting "Server Error".
In other words, there is no error in the code, but I'm guessing the error is in the access of the data or comparing the given StudentID in json format in Postman, with the ID model.

Comment: (But then you say "you can provide the GET method code" which implies that the GET method is a completely different function. So the fact that it works tells us nothing much really)

Comment: That doesn't help much sorry (I can only assume your top function is actually StudentManager.SaveProfile, despite it being called SaveProfileQuery). Though it does at least suggest that no matter what errors there are processing the request inside the Manager, you should get a 200 response.  Meaning either there's a routing issue or an exception somehow getting thrown in the controller function, but the debugger will tell you that.

Comment: The reason I'm telling you my GET method is working is because there's the same path and the same routing.
I'm getting a 200 response however, which means it's not a problem with the code, just the routing.

Comment: You still haven't told us what error you're seeing in postman or whether any exceptions are getting thrown in the debugger.

Comment: {
    "Status": {
        "Code": 2,
        "Message": "Server Error"
    }
}

Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in DAL.dll

Comment: Ok so not an HTTP error at all. "Server Error" is what your manager will return for ANY exception that's thrown. And your manager function WILL throw an exception if you pass in an ID that doesn't match any existing elements (because `Student` will be null, then you try to dereference it).

Comment: The NullReferenceException confirms exactly what I suggested was the problem in my 2nd comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
           XElement Student = (from u in xElement.Elements("Student")
                   where (string)u.Attribute("id") == objProfileRequest.StudentID.ToString()
                   select (u)).FirstOrDefault();

           Student.Element("Name").Value = objProfileRequest.Name;
```

This last line will cause a NullReferenceException if there is no student in the XML file matching the ID you're passing in.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, and you're totally right on this one.
But what if I'm trying to expand my database and add a new user without having to replace the existing user with that ID?

Comment: Then you need code to add a new XElement to the file, which I think you can work out if you got that much working yourself.